# How do I pronounce my surname?

Tags: pronunciation

I am not a native English Speaker, but I work with English speakers on a daily basis and they have always troubles pronouncing my surname, so they will often ask me to tell them how they can pronounce it.
My surname is Sulce.
I also tried a pronouncing service and they said ["Sorry, we can't pronounce that."](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/how-do-you-pronounce-the-word/sulce.html)
So, I would like to ask native speakers to help on defining the most correct way to pronounce it. What's the first pronunciation that comes to your mind for the word Sulce?

Comment: If I saw the word *sulce*, without any context, my instinct would be to pronounce it to rhyme with *pulse*.

Comment: The correct way to pronounce your surname is of course the way **you** pronounce it. If other people can’t pronounce that, that’s their problem, not yours. They can do their best. _Sulce_ looks very non-English, so without knowing what your native language is (or alternatively, what language the name comes from), it’s impossible to give an ‘intuitive’ pronunciation. I’d probably guess at either [sʌls] or [sʌlsi] or [sʌltʃi] or [sʌlseɪ] or [sʌltʃeɪ] or [sʊlsi] or [sʊltʃi] or [sʊlseɪ] or [sʊltʃeɪ] (in more or less random order) if I were to make a guess without knowing where it comes from.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How long does it take to learn the IPA to get to the point where one can sight-read it (but not necessarily write it) without too much effort?

Comment: @DanBron I'd say probably not too long—a couple of days’ worth of practice, and you should be good, at least as far as broad English transcription like what I wrote above goes. [This Wikipedia help page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English) is a good place to start—it gives good correspondences between (their choice of) IPA symbols and the normal vowel sets used for English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, that's encouraging! Thank you.

Comment: For me, it's so obviously a foreign name that I'd pronounce the last 'e'. I think my first guess would Sullchee, *sultry* with a 'ch'.

Comment: @Dan Bron - Sorry to answer a question to addressed to JBJ. I use IPA a lot and I've never learned it. I just refer to a table, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English - Note you have to be aware of which dialect the table refers to. You can find them for individual dialects as well.

Comment: Ardit. S - I don't think we can help by *reading* your name. We either have to hear it or see the phonetic symbols. In general we don't know how to pronounce even some *English* names until we have heard them!

Comment: Pronunciation is a strange thing in English. In many cases, spelling doesn't set the pronunciation of words. It's more how different people from different places say a particular word.

Comment: @Robusto I think what he means is a text-to-speech service or tool.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Thanks. I do the same, but I was wondering how long it takes to go "legit".

Comment: Ardit S. - Here's a suggestion - If you go to somewhere like Youtube, you can join and then record your name (provided your computer/device has a microphone). Then you can return here and provide us with the URL. If we hear you say it, we'll be able to answer.

Comment: If you're looking for an easy way to textually instruct average English speakers to pronounce your name reasonably well, it would be very helpful if you could somehow first let us know how it's actually pronounced. Perhaps tell us what language the name is natively from, or give us a recording of yourself pronouncing it (slowly and clearly).

Comment: The way I pronounce my name in my native language is sʊltʃe.
The last e is pronounced like "e" in get.

Answer (score 3):

In light of the clarification "The way I pronounce my name in my native language is sʊltʃe. The last e is pronounced like 'e' in get." in comments:

Then a pragmatic textual way to instruct English speakers would be to write that the name "rhymes with PULL-chay" or "rhymes with pull-CHAY", depending on the stress.

The English "AY" may not sound to you especially similar to the "E" of your name, but I assure it's subjectively similar to most native English speakers, and it is as close as a reasonable majority of them will get to with simple instructions.

Comment: Surely "sull-chee" is a much better approximation at the correct pronunciation, and just as understandable to English speakers as "sull-chay"?

Comment: @Marthaª, I disagree. "Sull" would be pronounced with an /ʌ/, unlike pull with an /ʊ/. "Chee" will certainly be pronounced with an /iː/, whereas "chay" with an /eɪ/ is both physically closer to the actual sound (in most English dialects) and psychologically closer - think of how native English speakers pronounce the endings of _soufflé_ or _résumé_. I could see a case for an /ə/ ending (if the /e/ is unstressed in the OP's name and) if it were straightforward to briefly and unambiguously indicate in text for generic readers without any linguistics background - but that's not the case.

Comment: The 'e' in 'get' is [ɛ] (epsilon) in almost all varieties of English, and most of the English-speaking world doesn't have [e] (eta) by itself (only as part of diphthongs, like in 'date' and 'day'). So which sound is it at the end of this name?

Comment: @JPmiaou, I deduce the name is Albanian, so the original sound is probably something in the range of [e̞] through [ɛ]. These are not distinctions you can easily convey in English text for a general lay audience, and (since English restricts its /ɛ/ to diphthongs and closed syllables) it's not reasonable to expect English speakers to routinely reproduce them. A reasonable, useful solution to the OP's problem is to invite English speakers to approximate the sound with the English /eɪ/, ⟨ay⟩, as is routinely done with French names.

Answer (score 2):

The lack of clear and consistent pronunciation rules in English for a word like this is why people ask you how you pronounce it.  The correct pronunciation of names is very dependent on the cultural context where you are from, and **the way you pronounce it is the correct way**. When somebody asks you, say what you would say when introducing yourself (like "My name is ____ ____") and then they can hear the pronunciation.

If you are yourself unsure, your parents and/or other family members with the same surname are likely the best folks to ask.  If you don't like the way your family members pronounce it, you can choose a different way and **the way you want it pronounced is the correct way,** with the possible exception of family settings when speakers might correctly feel it's not *your* name they are pronouncing.

In general, it's important to keep in mind the objectives for communication.  In most cases when someone is using your name, the speaker's intent is likely to uniquely identify you in a way that respects your relative uniqueness.  This intent is even more likely to be the case when the speaker is asking or has asked you about how to pronounce your name.  When that intent is present, **whatever pronunciation** which still leaves that intent discernible (even if only from tone and context) could be considered "correct" in that it achieves success in the communicative goal.

When I read your name, I have a few hypotheses about how it might be pronounced, but lack enough information about where you and/or your family are from.
My first guess is that it's like the Spanish "[dulce](http://audio1.spanishdict.com/audio?lang=es&text=dulce)" (links go to audio) but with an S instead of a D at the beginning.  To some extent, the meaning of whatever word you tell people to use to remember your name pronunciation will become mentally associated with you; "dulce" means "sweet" which I think of as being a generally positive association but it depends a bit on your style and personality and what you're going for.
[Dan Bron's guess](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264038/how-do-i-pronounce-my-surname/264042#comment580399_264038) that it's pronounced like "[pulse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/audio.php?file=pulse001&word=pulse)" with an "s" instead of a "p" would probably be my second guess.
My third guess, [ˈsəl-sē] would give the final e more of an an i sound, like the first syllable from "[sultan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/audio.php?file=sultan01&word=sultan)" followed by [see](http://www.merriam-webster.com/audio.php?file=see00001&word=see).  In that way it's kind of like "[Sochi](http://www.merriam-webster.com/audio.php?file=ggsoch01&word=Sochi)" with an "ul" sound ([pull](http://www.merriam-webster.com/audio.php?file=pull0001&word=pull) without p) instead of the o.  This is similar to Peter Shor's guess, but a different explanation.

Comment: Of course,  the first syllable of *sultan* has the same sound as the *ul* of *pulse.* Oh. Perhaps it doesn't... IPA FTW.